# Yosemite OSX 10.10.1 Asset image not shown Properly

Tags: cocoa, xcode7, osx-yosemite, photoshop, macos-sierra

I am using OS Seiera and xcode 7.3.1 for making .dmg. Images with same properties are acting differently on Yosmemite. Some of them works perfectly but some are getting weird, as you can see images. What could be the issue in image I am using, as all are coming from same designer. Is there a slicing issue for from some property twicking should me made?

Thanks.

[image: Distored Image]

[image: Image using in assets]